# Python request has insecure MD2, MD4, MD5, or SHA1 hash function

Tags: python, security, python-requests, cryptography

Good day,

our security team detected issues using python Requests to have vulnerabilities.

*Use of insecure MD2, MD4, MD5, or SHA1 hash function.*

I looked at the code and found out some usage in auth.py lines 154 and 148.

```
def md5_utf8(x):
      if isinstance(x, str):
          x = x.encode('utf-8')
          return hashlib.md5(x).hexdigest()

  def sha_utf8(x):
      if isinstance(x, str):
          x = x.encode('utf-8')
          return hashlib.sha1(x).hexdigest()
```

My question is, can I remove it? I know altering the base code is bad but I just want this to end.

will it affect the code? can I set the default to "SHA-256"

Comment: What calls `md5_utf8` and `sha_utf8`?  What does your security team recommend doing with these functions?  No one here can really answer, since unless these functions aren't called at all, changing them to some other hash algorithm will have downstream impacts of some sort.

Comment: It would also impact security. If only small ASCII strings are hashed then the security impact may be minimal. If the input is large and may be changed by an adversary then the impact might be very big, especially for MD5 where collisions are just a second away.

Comment: @AnonCoward the security team want this to be changed or removed - they did not specify how they just saw this with some bandit app.

Comment: Again, no one here can tell you what to do.  Changing the hash algorithm will necessarily change its output.  We can't know if that's a big deal for whoever calls these functions.

Comment: As a first step you could try replacing the old hashes with a new hash that produces the same size output.  That should reduce downstream effects somewhat.  That may mean running SHA3 and shrinking the output to, say, 128 bits when replacing MD5.

Comment: @rossum sorry I am not familiar with "re-hashing"